# Prints failing and there is resin hardened on the build plate in areas with no model on Elegoo Mars 3 Pro

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, resin, elegoo-mars, chitubox

I have been printing for years and I have no idea what is going on now. My prints are not coming out and random areas of the build plate have hardened resin where there should be nothing. These are pretty simple objects that are 3mm thick.

[image: After print complete]

[image: Chitu Screenshot]

[image: settings]

[image: Printer Settings]

Comment: In order to *accurately* answer your question, we will need some more details... please [edit] and update your question with any recent changes that you may have made, along with any settings used. Other details will probably also be required as well.